# Refresh GridView in xamarin.forms xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a GridView and each tile contains user-specific details hence I would like a refresh on this view if the user's details had to change while using the app. I've tried the following approach by adding a refresh for one of my tiles but this doesn't work. Is there any other way to achieve this for the whole gridView?

**Xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="cardBalance" >
            <Image Source="GiftCard.jpg" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CardImage"/>
            <Image Source="store2.jpg" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Image Source="GridTrans.jpg" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Image Source="ProfileBg2.JPG" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Image Source="gridSettings.JPG" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />

        <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListView x:Name="CardBalance" HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="CardBalance_Refreshing">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 x:Name="Layout">
                                <Frame>

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Label Text="Card Balance:" TextColor="Black"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Balance}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding CustomerLogo}" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60"></Image>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollView>

        <Label Text=" Tap to view detail" TextColor="Gainsboro" FontSize="14"  FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CardTile"/>
        <Label Text=" Tap to view all card balances" TextColor="#64676b" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MultipleCards"/>


        <Label Text=" Transactions" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="TransactionTile"/>
        <Label Text=" Promotions" TextColor="White" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  x:Name="PromoTile"/>
        <Label Text=" My Profile" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="ProfileTile" />
        <Label Text=" Settings" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"   x:Name="SettingsTile"/>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

Xaml.cs

```
public async void LoadCards()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Requests.Cards> cd = new List<Requests.Cards>();
            var content = "";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var RestUrl = Settings.RestUrl + "/api/Customer/GetCustomerCards?CustomerID=" + Helpers.Settings.storecustID;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RestUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Giftworx-App", Helpers.Settings.Usertoken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(RestUrl);

            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Requests.Cards>>(content);

            CardBalance.ItemsSource = Items;
            TapGestureRecognizer cardsLabel = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                cardsLabel.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Navigation.PushAsync(new Cards());

                };

                CardTile.GestureRecognizers.Add(cardsLabel);         
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exception = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void CardBalance_Refreshing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadCards();
        CardBalance.IsRefreshing = false;          
    }
```

Comment: Does "but this doesn't work" mean that you have get the new image but the image in the listView doesn't show the new image? Please declare more details about your issue.

Comment: Sorry, what image are you talking about? I mean the refresh that I was explaining is not working

Comment: You mean the LoadCards() method not working?

Comment: You are binding to Balance and CustomerLogo. Do those properties call a NotifyPropertyChanged event?

Comment: If you can, add the code for either the Balance or CustomerLogo properties.

Comment: @dev1998, Nope those properties do not call NotifyPropertyChanged. I just have a class with all the properties. I've added the method where Balance and CustomerLogo are coming from

Comment: Refreshing="CardBalance_Refreshing". Can you please post the code for "CardBalance_Refreshing".

Comment: @dev1998 Check edit, I've added it

Comment: This all looks reasonable. Have you tried running it with a debugger? Does the refreshing method get hit? If there are new details can you see them in the Items?